# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings getting null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I did not realize that: 'have a web.config in a separate class library and' was reading the web.config app setting from different web application.

I am using VS2010 target framework 3.5

I don't know what is wrong here but I am getting `null` when I try to get `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StoreId"];`

```
private string _storeid = GetStoreId;

public static string GetStoreId
{
    get
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StoreId"];
    }
}
```

**web.config:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StoreId" value="123" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Is this in your main app? In a class library? In a web application or web site??

Comment: Hi @Nick can you please revise the correct answer? It's been 7 yrs and I posted a better solution.

Answer (score 66):

If you are **UNIT TESTING** you need **A COPY** of the **APP.CONFIG** inside the **UNIT TEST PROJECT**

Comment: At the very least make a **shortcut file to the App.Config** - in general *you should never duplicate code files* unless via a version control system. If you can try do it with DI and Mocking the App.Config in your unit tests.

Comment: This was the solution to my issue.  I had to pull the tags from my web.config and put them in the app.config in between the <configuration> branch. 
 Once I did that my unit testing started working beautifully.

Comment: Why do we have to scroll down so far to get this answer? Can someone move it up?

Comment: I think i must have trained myself to ignore any posts with caps lock in them, because I scrolled straight past this at first... and then scrolled back up and realised this was the *exact* solution to by problem...

Comment: I agree with what @JeremyThompson wrote. However, instead of "shortcut", I would call it link. Meaning create a link to your file inside another project. I would recommend to simply put the configuration file in a shared folder under the solution and have the relevant projects all share it by adding a linked file inside each project. This is what was mentioned in this solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60107554/4441211) and I think it is complementary to this solution.

Answer (score 23):

## Update

You can have an AfterTargets in your CsProj file that copies the config:

```
<Target Name="CopyAppConfig" AfterTargets="Build" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <CreateItem Include="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll.config">
         <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FilesToCopy"/>
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)testhost.dll.config" />
</Target>
```

## Problem

**The usual cause for this is due to context.**

## Cause

When you have a solution with two projects, if the `App/Web.Config` is in the main project it wont work if the context of the running application is the second project such as a library, unit test, etc.

## Conundrum

To read values from the config in other projects (with `System.Configuration`) you'll need to move/copy the config file to the project with the running context. Unfortunately duplicating files defeats the tenants of good programming; OOP, Source Code Management, SOLID, etc.

## Cool Solution

**A nifty solution is adding config file shortcuts in other projects so you only update one file:**

[image]

*It would be nice to divide the contents of  `config` files across project's. Elegantly, like Sharing Assembly Files as per answer #2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319582/495455 but alas it's by **context***

Comment: Same goes for a console app referencing and calling into a class library.  Settings go into console's app.config and can be called from class library like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]`

Comment: Downvoted. This is fighting symptoms, not fixing problems. This makes future updates error prone, as you may want to have separate config values for each project.

Comment: @Spukee can you provide àn answer with à solution?

Comment: @JeremyThompson: The accepted answer is fine. My main concern is that providing a link will give you a false sense of security. Maintaining each file separately requires a little more discipline but that's never a bad thing. It also means you are very aware of what's going on, rather than 'assume' everything is okay.

Comment: *The accepted answer is fine* - no it isn't even a solution. You can see the file in Solution Explorer is a shortcut, sorry I'm not catering for people who want to maintain copies of essentially the same file! Rookies.

Answer (score 12):

**Disclaimer** ;)  *This post is not to answer OP as it is too late but definitely it would help the readers who end up to this page.*

**Problem I faced** : `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uName"]` returning `null` in my C# web api project.

**Basic  Things I checked for** :

**1)** In code `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uName"]` , I was using exact key '`uName`' as I had in `web.config` file,

i.e

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="uName" value="myValue" />
</appSettings>
```

**Checked** that I haven't **mis typed** as `userName` instead of `uName` etc.

2) Since it is a *Web API* project it would have a file as `web.config` instead of `app.config` , and that too in **root folder** of your project. [refer the image].

[image]

**Solution** :

The solution that worked for me ,

**Changed** `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uName"]` to `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uName"]`

**and**

made sure that I had

```
<appSettings>
          <add key="uName" value="myValue" />
</appSettings>
```

in the **right**  file ie.

Right file is **not** web.config in View folder

**neither** the debug or release web.config

[image]

Comment: This was my mistake. I was using the wrong web config. AppSettings is in the other web config. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @BernardV, happy to help :) !!

Answer (score 8):

and:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StoreId" value="123" />
</appSettings>
```

is located in the `web.config` file of your ASP.NET application and not in some `app.config` file you've added to your class library project in Visual Studio, right? You can't be possibly getting `null` if this is the case. If you've added this to an `app.config` of you class library project in Visual Studio then getting null is perfectly normal behavior.

Comment: its located in `web.config` in my web application

Comment: its worth noting that if you have a test harness running the code, then *its* app.config needs to have the setting you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I just got answer DLL are called from another project not in the project where there are create.so entries in App.config should b move to calling project config file.

For example i have 2 project in my solution one class library and other console application.i have added class library reference in Console application.So if i add app.config file in class library project it through null exception.it works when i added app.config in console application.Hope it works

Answer (score 2):

App settings are loaded into ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, but User settings (in Properties settings in your project properties) are not.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, right-click on the config file, select Properties, and then change "Copy to Output Directory" to either "Copy always" or "Copy if newer".

Alternatively, manually add the following section as a child of the  element in your .csproj file (this one is for "Copy always" for file "App.config"):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="App.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of these solutions but none worked for me. I was attempting to use a 'web.config' file. Everything was named correctly and the files were in the proper location, but it refused to work. I then decided to rename my 'web.config' file to 'app.config' and just like that, it worked.

So if you are having this issue with a 'web.config' file be sure to rename it to 'app.config'.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was testing a Class Library (.dll). They were both in the same project but the App.config for the library had the settings I needed. The App I had written to test needed the settings because *it* was running the library.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem as I copied a project from the file explorer and renamed the project. This copied the Debug folder and as I didn't have it set to 'Copy if newer' it didn't overwrite the old App.config file.

Just delete the Debug folder and rebuild. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above answer and I would like to add few more points

1. you should make sure you don't put space before and after the :
   see code below:

   ```
   private static string Client_ID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
   ```

   if you put space between ida: ClientId it will not work and will return null
2. make sure your key value names are correct
3. you can try WebConfigurationManager

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me just now, only when calling it from another project.
Apparently, at the other project, the reference has not been defined as a Service Reference but rather as a Connected Service. I deleted the reference and added it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting"];
```

1. Make sure config file is in the same folder as code referencing it. Create a
   helper class if it is not. Duplicating this could cause confusion should
   someone forget it exists in two places.
2. Keep app settings in an app.config and not a web.config for AppSettings.I had this issue with a key in the web.config.