# Read and write settings programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, properties, configuration, settings

I've got the following example content generated by the Settings-Designer in Visual Studio 2015:

```
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Test.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogFileFolder" serializeAs="String">
        <value>logs</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="sPluginsFolder" serializeAs="String">
        <value>plugins</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="sLangBaseName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Test.Resources.Language.Test</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ConfirmationExit" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
    </Test.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now I want to access, for example, the variable "ConfirmationExit" within my code. In first I tried with `Properties.Settings.Default` which is working nicely, but I want to retrieve the configuration keys more generic and provide a `ConfigurationService` which can be used by any other .NET program.

I tried playing around with the `ConfigurationManager`, but I didn't get the values of the different settings/properties. I always got `null` if I tried something like this:

```
string test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfirmationExit"];
```

How can I PROGRAMMATICALLY read AND write properties/settings defined within the app.config file with the use of the Settings-Designer. Thx for any help ;)

**UPDATE:**

Maybe I have to mention, that there is a namspace used as XML element (I think this is generated by the designer or soemthing else?!):

```
<Test.Properties.Settings>
```

inside of

```
<applicationSettings>
```

Also please remind:
This is a project structure like this:

```
1. Project_Common

2. Project_Main

   |-- Project_Common

3. Project_Plugin1

   |-- Project_Common

4. Project_Plugin2

   |-- Project_Common

...
```

In Project_Common there should be a ConfigurationService which can retrieve all properties of all applications. Maybe the constructor has to have a parameter to inject settings or something.

Comment: Is this web application or desktop application?

Comment: It is a desktop application completely written in .NET.

Comment: Look at the results of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. My guess is that you are reading another app.config by accident. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280970/configurationmanager-appsettings-getting-null

Answer (score 1):

```
            string test = Properties.Settings.Default.ConfirmationExit;
```

From MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

Comment: Yes, but if you don't have this file in your project, because it is outsourced for other projects (dependency to a "Common" project), this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

read:
    Settings.Default.{propertyName}
so in your case for example
    Settings.Default.ConfirmationExit
reads ConfirmationExit-Value

Set it:
Settings.Default.ConfirmationExit = false

Write:
    Settings.Default.Save();

Comment: Also the same here. See my comment at the answer from @Astx