# ASP.NET Core 2.2 How to share web.config/launchSettings.json files among projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this solution structure:

- `AppOne.Account`
- `AppOne.Admin`
- `AppOne.System`
- `AppOne.Data`
- `AppOne.ClassLibrary`

`AppOne.Account`, `AppOne.Admin` and `AppOne.System` are `ASP.NET` Core Application Projects. The rest are libraries.

Currently I have to manually copy and paste the same web.config file to each of them when I deploy and even in development, I have to copy and paste the `launchSettings.json` file as it contains their environment variables that I need.

Is it possible to store the `web.config` or `launchSettings.json` file in a folder and then reference it in my `Startup.cs`.

I am thinking of storing it in a Solution folder and then reading the in. However, I am unsure if that is possible and I am also unsure of where to read it from.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535980/495455

Comment: I have just read through that. I kind of understand it but where do I reference the web.config file in my other folder? Do I need to add code in or is a reference enough?

Comment: You don't "reference" the web.config. You put the app/web.config file in the project (or a short cut to the single Config file that actually lives in another folder). Then in code you use `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting...` and that will look for the config file in the **running project**. It's context based. If you are running the main project it'll look at the main project for the config, if you're running a Unit Test project then it'll expect a config file (or a shortcut) lives in the root of the unit testing project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "reference" the web.config. You put the app/web.config file in the project (or a short cut to the single Config file that actually lives in another folder).

Then in code you use `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting...` and that will look for the config file in the running project. It's context based.

If you are running the main project it'll look at the main project for the config, if you're running a Unit Test project then it'll expect a config file (or a shortcut) lives in the root of the unit testing project.

**A nifty solution is adding config file shortcuts in other projects so you only update one file:**

[image]