# How to use app.config for multiple projects in same solution?

Tags: c#, webforms

I have 2 projects in single solution and both should be using common app.config file.
By doing web search, i came across solution => Add config using "Add as a link" option. But this option is not available in visual studio 2019.

Can someone help how to achieve this?

[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekw1e.png)

Comment: `Add as link`  **IS** available in VS2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add New Solution Folder (menu item on the solution node of the Solution Explorer) called "Shared".
2. Add/create an app.config file to the folder.
3. For each project that needs using the app.config file, Add Existing Item -> navigate to the file location -> select the file -> press down-pointing triangle on the `Add` button of the item/file selection dialog and select `Add as Link`.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Thanks a lot for the help!