# Read web.config (using System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler) from class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am working on an asp.net core project in which I wrote a custom library for retrieving data from restful API. I am planning to refer this class library in my project and I need to pass some details like TenantId, ClientId & etc from the web project to the class library

The below image is my current setup but upon running the code I always got **NULL**

**Configuration.cs**

This class are found in my Class Library

[image]

**Web.config**

[image]

Can someone help me on this matter. Thank you

Comment: asp.net or asp.net core?

Comment: Can you confirm if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535980/495455 - If so then we can close as a duplicate.

Comment: asp.net core buddy @JeremyLakeman

Comment: web.config is for IIS configuration. While it used to be how you would configure an aspx project. In an asp.net core project, IIS is just a reverse proxy. While I'm sure its possible to write a web.config configuration provider, IMHO you should just adopt the new appsettings.json way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0.